# If the mean of four of six given numbers is known, what is the mean of the other two?

Tags: arithmetic

> Four of the six numbers 
>   $$1867,\quad 1993,\quad 2019,\quad 2025,\quad 2109,\quad \text{and}\quad 2121 $$
>   have a mean of 2008. What is the mean of the other two numbers?

I would like to get help for this problem because i want to find a way to answer this problem without using guess and check. thank you :)

Comment: Please make the body of your message self-contained, not relying on the subject for content.

Comment: This is a great example of how math works (in an elementary example). A beginner will think (I'm guessing): compute -all- means of subsets of size four out of six, find one that is 2008, and then compute the means of what is left over. And of course this is too hard, too much computation. And the beginner would then just give up, but the more experienced would try -not- to do all that work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are the four numbers whose mean is 2008. That means that
$$\frac{a+b+c+d}{4} = 2008.$$

If $e$ and $f$ are the other two numbers, you want to find
$$\frac{e+f}{2}.$$

Well, if you know $e+f$, you can figure out their mean (just divide by $2$). And you happen to know how much the sum of **all six** numbers is (you can just compute it). Can you use the information you have to figure out what $e+f$ must be?

---

*Added.* Given the comment by the OP below, it seems the hint above is insufficient.

*You don't need to know the four numbers.* Nobody is asking you what the four numbers are, or what the other two numbers are. All you need to know is what $e+f$ is. Because once you know what the sum of "the other two numbers" is, then you can just divide that sum by $2$ and get the mean.

Now, you know what $a+b+c+d+e+f$ (the sum of all six numbers) is: it's
$$1867 + 1993 + 2019 + 2025 + 2109 + 2121 =12134.$$
(I'm not saying that $a$ is 1867; I'm just saying that adding all six numbers is 12134).

You also know what the sum of the four numbers whose mean is 2008 is: because you know that $(a+b+c+d)/4 = 2008$, so that means that the sum of the four numbers is $4\times 2008 = 8032$.

So: the sum of all six numbers is $12134$. The sum of the four numbers with  mean 2008 is $8032$.

How much is the sum of "the other two numbers"?

And if the sum of the other two numbers it that much, how much is their mean?

Comment: but what if i do not know the four numbers whose mean is 2008 because in the problem, you are not given the exact four numbers. You have to find them. I love the equations but how would use it for this problem? im alittle confused here

Comment: @Briana791: The whole point is that you **don't need to know the four numbers**. You just need to know how much they add up to. I've added a fuller explanation.

Comment: ohhh ok im understanding you...thank you....just one more thing...what would be the sum of the other two numbers?

Comment: nevermind i got the answer you just subtract the sum of the six numbers and the sum of the four numbers

Answer (score 6):

Hint: If $X$ is the mean of $N$ numbers then their sum is...?

Comment: ok so this is what i did...I made x = 2008 and N = 4. 2008 x 4 = 8032 so the sum of the four numbers is 8032....what do i do from here to get the four numbers?

Comment: @Briana791: Read the question: **you don't need to get the four numbers.** Nobody is asking you to find the four numbers. You don't care what the four numbers are. What you want to know is what the mean of "the other two numbers" is.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the six given integers is $1867+1993+2019+2025+2109+2121=12134$.

The four of these integers that have a mean of 2008 must have a sum of $4(2008)=8032$. (We do not know which integers they are, but we do not actually need to know.)

Thus, the sum of the remaining two integers must be $12134-8032=4102$.

You know the next step! Just divide it by two.

Answer (score 0):

First, we find the total of the numbers, which is 12134. Then, we subtract the total of the 4 numbers, the average times 4 (8032). The result is the sum of the two numbers, 4102. The average is 2051 (4102/2).